# Why does my second function call prevent the first one to execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I use this:

```
.delay(1000)
    .queue(function () {
    $this.parent().removeClass('shown');
    $this.next().removeAttr('style');
});
```

Then `removeClass('shown')` is not carried out. It *is* carried out when I use:

```
.delay(1000)
    .queue(function () {
    $this.parent().removeClass('shown');
    //$this.next().removeAttr('style');
});
```

I'm not getting any error or warning with either snippet though.

**EDIT** I made a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RubenGeert/rRL6u/). After opening and closing the search form (by clicking the magnifying glass on the right), the `:hover` effect is gone and the `placeholder` text is not white (thus visible). Both effects are due to the class `shown` not being removed if I don't comment out the line below it.

**UPDATE**

I believe the problem is that `animate` clashes with `removeAttr('style')` since the former actually uses the `style` attribute. The selector seems OK since changing `$(this).next().removeAttr('style')` to `$(this).next().addClass('hello')` works fine.

[image][image]

Comment: have you tried, `$this.next(function(){$(this).removeAttr('style');});`

Comment: I think more code is required for this one, a simple fiddle works http://jsfiddle.net/cda7a/

Comment: Your code is working fine. See [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5TD3f/). I think you are either setting your `$this` incorrectly in the code not shown or maybe the targeted element using `parent()/next()` are not what you expect them to be. Could also be CSS that the inline style might contain or similar. It is hard to tell at this time. Could you add the rest of the relevant code?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: the second line always works fine (unless commented out of course). But the first line only works if the second line is commented out. I should see the class "shown" disappear in Firefox Developer tools but it only does so with the second line commented out. I'll add all code up to this point to my OP, OK?

Comment: can u share ur html code?

Comment: @Neha: I made a JSFiddle of it. Please see the edits in my OP. I haven't managed to solve the problem yet. I'll put a bounty on it if necessary.

Comment: @RubenGeert What about http://jsfiddle.net/Ty2cR/ ? I guess that works, .shown is removed from the form and style attr is removed. I removed the queue wrapper function and put the calls on separate lines. Not a big fan on all the chaining (decreases readability imho :-)).

Comment: @Bjorn: thank you, I didn't know it could be written like that as well. However, your fiddle doesn't work entirely. It *does* remove the `shown` class but the line below (removing the `style` for `next()` (which is `form input`) is not done. So the `:hover` effect is still gone after closing the search form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did changes and its works .. (let me know if its not expected)

1) as u wish to remove the shown class on animation start, use the "start" property.

2) add queue before end() method.

```
    $('body').click(function(e){
    $this = $(e.target);
    if($this.is('form.shown #close-search')){
       //Need to stop anim before reset it again.
        $this.next().stop();
        $this
            .next() /*input*/
            .animate(
                {'right':'-9.5em'},{duration:1000,queue:true , start :
                 function(){ $this.parent().removeClass('shown'); } })
            .queue(
                function(){
                      $this.next().removeAttr('style');                        
                } )
             .end()
             .delay(1000)
            .parent()
            .css('background','none')
            .addClass('hidden');            

    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rRL6u/4/)

**Update** : Found the culprit .. we need to stop anim before re-starting it agaian on next click.

Comment: Thank you! However, it does not work entirely yet: the first time opening and closing is fine. The second time opening is OK too but it **doesn't close the second time**.

Comment: @RubenGeert I updated the demo check now its I think u need to release the element from last anim before starting it again.

Comment: it took a little effort but things seem to work perfectly now. Thanks a million, you rock!